# Vue Laravel not showing data from method

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I know I am blind because I've been looking at this for 2 days off and on and I think I am just eye stuck on what is really going on. Below is the code. What SHOULD happen is an array of data should be shown into a modal. I can see the data as "rooms" in web inspector with all the fields, but it isnt populating into the v-for - all im asking for is a little help if you can see where I screwed up

```
<!-- This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ -->
<template>
  <TransitionRoot as="template" :show="open">
    <Dialog as="div" class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" @close="open = false">
      <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
        <TransitionChild as="template" enter="ease-out duration-300" enter-from="opacity-0" enter-to="opacity-100" leave="ease-in duration-200" leave-from="opacity-100" leave-to="opacity-0">
          <DialogOverlay class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
        </TransitionChild>

        <!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. -->
        <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
        <TransitionChild as="template" enter="ease-out duration-300" enter-from="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95" enter-to="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100" leave="ease-in duration-200" leave-from="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100" leave-to="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95">
          <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg px-4 pt-5 pb-4 text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:p-6">

              <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" @click="open = false">
                <div class="hidden sm:block absolute top-0 right-0 pt-4 pr-4">
                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                <XIcon class="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                </div>
              </button>

            <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
            <div class="flex flex-col">
              <div class="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                <div class="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                  <div class="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
                    <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                      <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Room
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Description
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Type
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col" class="relative px-6 py-3">
                            <span class="sr-only">Enter</span>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                        <tr v-for="room in chatRooms" :key="room.id">
                          <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="flex items-center">
                              <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                                <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" :src="room.image" alt="" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="ml-4">
                                <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                                  {{ room.name }}
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-900">{{ room.description }}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full" :class="[room.is_private === 'Public' ? 'bg-green-100 text-green-800' : room.is_private === 'Private' ? 'bg-red-100 text-red-800' : '']">
                              {{ room.is_private }}
                            </span>
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                            <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Enter</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </TransitionChild>
      </div>
    </Dialog>
  </TransitionRoot>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { Dialog, DialogOverlay, DialogTitle, TransitionChild, TransitionRoot } from '@headlessui/vue'
import { ExclamationIcon, XIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/outline'

export default {
  props: ['rooms'],
  data: function () {
    return {
        chatRooms: [],
        rooms: [], 
    }
  },
  methods: { 
    getRooms() {
      axios.get('/chat/rooms')
          .then(response => {
              this.chatRooms = response.data;
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
          })
    }
  },
  components: {
    Dialog,
    DialogOverlay,
    DialogTitle,
    TransitionChild,
    TransitionRoot,
    ExclamationIcon,
    XIcon,
  },
  setup() {
    const open = ref(true)
    return {
      open,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: In the network tab of your browser, your query **/chat/rooms** is called and returns the data ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: When you **console.log(this.chatRooms)**, what is the output ?

Comment: the full array of rooms

Comment: in your controller, how do you send your data ? I mean your line **return response()..**

Comment: return ChatRoom::all();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not something anyone here could solve with the information provided. So I am typing this answer in a way that I hope will trigger some help to others.

When you are doing a v-for snippet, it is important to remember what data is being pulled for processing. In my case, the following line was the issue

```
<span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full" :class="[room.is_private === 'Public' ? 'bg-green-100 text-green-800' : room.is_private === 'Private' ? 'bg-red-100 text-red-800' : '']">
```

room.is_private is a boolean not the data I want to visualize. So by saying Public and Private, I was breaking the for statement. By changing them to True and False, I was able to process the v-for statement and actually get the code to load. The solution I used was as follows. Note there are 2 versions of true and false. This is because Postgres and sqlite both expect to see the response differently. I noticed this when it worked local with 'true' but pgsql on the deployment didn't work. So this Is why the code is this way

```
                                                            <div v-if="room.is_private === true" class="rounded-full py-1 px-2 bg-red-100 text-red-800">
                                                                        <span>Private</span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div v-else-if="room.is_private === false" class="rounded-full py-1 px-2 bg-green-100 text-green-800">
                                                                        <span>Public</span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div v-else-if="room.is_private === 'true'" class="rounded-full py-1 px-2 bg-red-100 text-red-800">
                                                                        <span>Private</span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div v-else-if="room.is_private === 'false'" class="rounded-full py-1 px-2 bg-green-100 text-green-800">
                                                                        <span>Public</span>
                                                                </div>
```

The important lesson here is to make sure you sample the data and fields before running into code making mistakes on the type of data being requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Maybe this is the cause of your problem.

Add this piece of code before `methods: {}` and tell me :

```
created() {
   this.getRooms();
},
```